# What is the correct way of expressing this probability mass function?

Tags: probability, conditional-probability

Suppose I have a discrete random variable $S$. Now further suppose that I have a random variable $X$ which is a continuous random variable on the real line. I wanted to express the p.m.f. $P[S=s]$ for $S$ using the expression:
\begin{equation}
P[S=s]= \int_{\mathbb{R}}P[S=s\mid x]P[x\mid s]dx
\end{equation}

A professor I spoke to mentioned that if both $S$ and $X$ were discrete, this expression would have been correct, however, given that $X$ is a continuous random variable, the way I have expressed it implies a zero probability (I suppose because of $P[x\mid s]$). I was told to express this correctly, I have to express it in terms of probability measures.

I have been spending the better part of yesterday on Shiryaev's probability book and on probability measures and Lebesgue integrals; but while I know he is correct about my incorrect expression, I am not sure exactly how  this needs to be expressed in terms of probability measures.

Comment: Not sure what you're trying do there. But I guess you need conditional density.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like you are trying to write the [law of total probability](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Law_of_total_probability#Continuous_case).  For a discrete random variable $S$ and a continuous conditioning random variable $X$ with marginal density $f_X$, you can write this as:

$$\mathbb{P}(S=s) = \int \limits_\mathbb{R} \mathbb{P}(S=s|X=x) f_X(x) \ dx.$$

Observe that the integrand here consists of the conditional probability mass for $S|X$ multiplied by the *marginal* density of $X$ (not the conditional density).  I see no reason you would need to write this in terms of the probability measures or the Lebesgue integral (since you know that $X$ is continuous here), but if you really want to do so then you can take the probability measure $\mu_X$ or the distribution function $F_X$ for $X$ and write the relevant result as:

$$\mathbb{P}(S=s) = \int \limits_\mathbb{R} \mathbb{P}(S=s|X=x) \ d F_X(x) = \int \limits_\mathbb{R} \mathbb{P}(S=s|X=x) \ d \mu_X.$$

Comment: Hi Ben. You are correct. However, I noticed I made an error in formulating the question, which explains the unnecessary conditioning in the second term. My intended question was, suppose there $S$ AND $I$ are the discrete random variables, and I wish to express $P[S=s\mid I=i]=\int_{\mathbb{R}}P[S=s\mid I=i,X=x]P[X=x \mid I=i]dx$, where as before $X$ is continuous. How would the formulation would this specific case be?

Comment: Probably best to ask this as a new question.